# Unconsistent natural ordering for TreeMap

Tags: java, equals, treemap, compareto

Is it possible to create a TreeMap in which the natural ordering of the keys is not consistent(key1.equals(key2) = true, key1.compareTo(k3) = 1, key2.compareTo(key3) = -1)?
If I will change the compareTo so that this won't happen but there will be keys where key1.equals(key2) = false but key1.compareTo(key2)=0 will it be good?

Comment: Implement the `compareTo` method incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get unpredictable behaviour as you'll be using the `TreeMap` outside of its declared constraints.

The `Map` interface is declared to rely on the `equals()` method, and the `TreeMap` to rely on `compareTo()`. So both methods are relevant and should be consistent, otherwise you can't rely on the outcome. Even if it works in some JVM version / implementation, it might break in a different one.

Technically, the `TreeMap` uses the `compareTo()` method, so you might get away with a `compareTo()` that's ok in itself, only incompatible with `equals()`, but I surely won't recommend that!